# Android: How can I get an image link on public Facebook page if I have its name

Tags: android, facebook

How can I get the direct link to an image if I know its name (safe_image.php.jpg) on a public auto-generated Facebook page? [enter link description here](https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Life-in-Ruins/103139833059656) Using code of course

Thank you :)

Edit 1:

I implemented it with help of this [Graph API Reference /{user-id}/picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture) but the returned picture url in jason is always 50x50 px, here is my request code: How can I change the returned size to be larger?

```
        params.putString("height", "200");
        params.putString("type", "normal");
        params.putString("width", "200");
        params.putString("fields", "picture");
        new Request(session, "103139833059656", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
```

Comment: "Name" is not enough. You will have to know the page ID. Then you will have to use facebook SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata-step3

Comment: @Kasra I have the page id, and it's not a person page, it's an auto-generated page about country, person, event, etc. so is it possible to accomplish this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it is possible assuming you have the page ID. Consider this facebook page:
https://www.facebook.com/BCBlood

You have the id - which is:

```
148255255232181
```

Now all you need to do, is to call the following line and parse the response. Call this http get:

http://graph.facebook.com/148255255232181/picture?redirect=false&width=300&height=300

and the response would be:

```
{
   "data": {
      "height": 243,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/v/t1.0-1/10311943_731106673613700_2433559617326858334_n.jpg?oh=6f0532b666e476539b5f41b803896495&oe=5523F5C7&__gda__=1428226241_013b5598c756728eaf04d630f96256a8",
      "width": 243
   }
}
```

As you can see, the response contains a link to the profile picture.

EDIT, more details:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("height", "200");
    params.putString("type", "normal");
    params.putString("width", "200");
    params.putString("redirect", "false");


Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if(error != null) {
            Log.d("FB", "Facebook error - " + error.getErrorMessage());
            Log.d("FB", "Error code - " + error.getErrorCode());
            Log.d("FB", "JSON Response - " + error.getRequestResult());
            Log.d("FB", "Error Category - " + error.getCategory());

        } else {
            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject dataObject = 
                        new JSONObject((String)graphObject.getProperty("data"));

                        String pictureURL = 
                            dataObject.getString("url");
        // do something with pictureURL
        // ......

        }
    }
};

Request request= new Request(session, "103139833059656/picture", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()


RequestAsyncTask asyncTask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
asyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I implement this graph call in an Android Facebook request?

Comment: I updated my answer, could you please recheck the Edit 1. Thank you.

Comment: Again thank you, are you by any chance aware how to avoid retrieving the image cropped? I want the entire image, and if there is a need to, I'll crop it myself.

Comment: The type=normal indicates that you need an uncropped photo. Make sure you only include the height. Paste this into your bowser to see it: http://graph.facebook.com/humansofnewyork/picture?type=normal&redirect=false&height=200

Comment: That's really awesome, thanks ... Accepted and rated :)